# PHP DOMDocument - remove span by style attributes

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm trying to remove span tags with a specific style (preserving the text) but don't understand why the result is putting span text inside the first span in this example?

```
    $curr_notes = '<span style="color: rgb(226, 80, 65);"><br></span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">TEXT 1</span><br><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">TEXT2</span>';
    $pattern    = '//span[@style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"]';

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($curr_notes, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    foreach ($xpath->query($pattern) as $span) {

        while ($span->hasChildNodes()) {
            $child = $span->removeChild($span->firstChild);
            $span->parentNode->insertBefore($child, $span);
        }

        $span->parentNode->removeChild($span);
    }

    // Get the final HTML with span tags stripped
    $clean_notes = $dom->saveHTML();

    echo $clean_notes;
    // <span style="color: rgb(226, 80, 65);"><br>TEXT 1<br>TEXT2</span>

    // am expecting
    // <span style="color: rgb(226, 80, 65);"><br></span>TEXT 1<br>TEXT2
```

Answer (score 2):

`DOMDocument` is not ideal for processing HTML fragments like that, because `DOMDocument` expects a single root element node, when your HTML fragment contains multiple nodes at the top level. Because of this, when parsing, `DOMDocument` puts all subsequent nodes under the first element node it finds.

Ideally we would deal with this by creating a `DOMDocumentFragment` (`DOMDocument::createDocumentFragment()`). However, unfortunately, `DOMDocumentFragment` only has an `appendXML()` method and no `appendHTML()` method, which means your HTML will have to be valid XML to work properly.

Dealing with all this gets murky really fast:

1. If you are sure your HTML will never contain `<html><body>...` etc. elements of their own, then you could call `loadHTML()` without the `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` flag and save the HTML relative to the `<body>` element.

   However DOMDocument frustratingly doesn't have an easy way to output the "innerHTML" of nodes either, so you'll have to concatenate the children of `<body>`, with something like:

   ```php
   $curr_notes = '<span style="color: rgb(226, 80, 65);"><br></span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">TEXT 1</span><br><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">TEXT2</span>';
   $pattern    = '//span[@style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"]';

   $dom = new DOMDocument();
   $dom->loadHTML($curr_notes, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

   $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
   foreach ($xpath->query($pattern) as $span) {
     while ($span->hasChildNodes()) {
       // no need to save $span->firstChild in $child variable first
       $span->parentNode->insertBefore($span->firstChild, $span);
     }
     $span->parentNode->removeChild($span);
   }
   // get the <body>
   $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   // let's make sure we have a <body>
   if(!is_null($body)) {
     $clean_notes = '';
     // concatenate to get the "innerHTML" of <body>
     foreach($body->childNodes as $child) {
       $clean_notes .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
     }

     echo $clean_notes;
   }
   ```
2. If you are not sure whether your HTML will contain a `<html><body>...` structure, it gets even more murky, because now you don't know which node to save with `saveHTML()` (the whole document, or just the children of `<body>`?). So, now you have to do some probing first to see which case it is. One somewhat naive way to do this might be to test the original HTML string for the presence of `<html><body>...` with something like:

   ```php
   $isFullDocument = (bool) preg_match('/<html>\s*<body>/', $curr_notes);
   ```

   ...and then adjust the `saveHTML()` strategy accordingly.

   Be warned about me saying "naive", because above approach might fail in the (unlikely) event that `<html>\s*<body>` is somehow matched somewhere other than where expected, or perhaps you have a `<html><head><body>` (or similar) structure. So perhaps you need to come up with a more robust test.

Comment: The text I'm parsing will not have <html><body>. I'm a little less certain about nested tags, since it's the output of a WYSIWYG editor which does allow nested styles. I'm on the road but will give your suggestion a run shortly. Worse comes to worse, I could do reg replace on <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">any text</span>, I suppose. Thanks much for your reply.